# Dash-Plotly Update dash_table.DataTable from dcc.Dropdown but per some specific range of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I have been reading documentations as well as lots of posts in SO but am more confused than ever.
Below code runs and gets me Tables and Dropdowns but I'm stuck at this time on how to display table per dropdown.
The Table as a Column REM with numbers. The requirement is to display Table per range. For example 'Expired' is REM == 0 or less, 'Expiring 1-5' is REM == 1 to 5, 'Expiring 6-10' is REM from 6 to 10 and so on.
Looking at example; I sort of have idea what the callback function would look like but have no idea what to pass in df_0_days, df_5_days etc.

INPUT CSV file looks like:

[image]

```
import os
import csv
import json
import socket
import logging
import datetime
import subprocess
from dash_extensions.enrich import DashProxy, MultiplexerTransform
from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html, no_update
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import dash_daq as daq
import pandas as pd

os.system("")

current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
expired_date = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

expiry_date_5_days = current_datetime + datetime.timedelta(5)
expiry_date_10_days = current_datetime + datetime.timedelta(10)
expiry_date_15_days = current_datetime + datetime.timedelta(15)

df = pd.read_csv("testing_final_cert.csv")
count_df_total_certs = len(df.index)

print(df.to_string())

df_expired_list = {}
df_expiring_list_in_5_days = {}
df_expiring_list_in_10_days = {}
df_expiring_list_in_15_days = {}

counter = 0
for record in range(0, count_df_total_certs):

    df_subject = df.iloc[record]['subject']
    df_issuer = df.iloc[record]['issuer']
    df_start_date = df.iloc[record]['startDate']
    df_expiry_date = df.iloc[record]['endDate']
    df_rem_day = int(df.iloc[record]['REM'])
    df_owner = df.iloc[record]['OWNER']

    if (df_rem_day <= 0):
        df_expired_list.update({df_subject: df_rem_day})

        print("df_0_days:\n{0}".format(df.iloc[counter]))

    if ((df_rem_day > 0) and (df_rem_day <= 5)):
        df_expiring_list_in_5_days.update({df_subject: df_rem_day})

        print("df_5_days:\n{0}".format(df.iloc[counter]))

    if ((df_rem_day >= 6) and (df_rem_day <= 10)):
        df_expiring_list_in_10_days.update({df_subject: df_rem_day})

        print("df_10_days:\n{0}".format(df.iloc[counter]))

    if ((df_rem_day >= 11) and (df_rem_day <= 15)):
        df_expiring_list_in_15_days.update({df_subject: df_rem_day})

        print("df_15_days:\n{0}".format(df.iloc[counter]))

    counter = counter + 1

count_0_days = len(df_expired_list)
count_5_days = len(df_expiring_list_in_5_days)
count_10_days = len(df_expiring_list_in_10_days)
count_15_days = len(df_expiring_list_in_15_days)

df_count_of_expiring_list = [["Expired", "5-days", "10-days", "15-days"],
                             [count_0_days, count_5_days, count_10_days, count_15_days]]

app = DashProxy(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Col(html.Div([
        html.Label('Date filter'),
        dcc.Dropdown(id='date_filter_dropdown2',
                     className="m-2",
                     options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in
                              ["All", "Expired", "Expiring 1-5-days", "Expiring 6-10-days", "Expiring 11-15-days"]],
                     searchable=True,
                     value='All',
                     placeholder='Select Expiration Date Filter from dropdown...', )]), width=6
    ),

    dbc.Container([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            data=df.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
            id='df_table_id',
            page_action="native",
            page_current=0,
            page_size=15,
            sort_action="native",
            sort_by=[{'column_id': 'REM', 'direction': 'asc'}],
            style_as_list_view=False,
            fixed_rows={'headers': False},
        ),
    ], fluid=True),
])


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='df_table_id', component_property='data'),
    Input(component_id='date_filter_dropdown2', component_property='value')
)
def update_(value):
    if value == 'All':
        dff_merged = df
        return dff_merged.to_dict('records')

    if value == 'Expired':
        dff_merged = df_0_days
        return dff_merged.to_dict('records')

    if value == 'Expiring 5-days':
        dff_merged = df_5_days
        return dff_merged.to_dict('records')

    if value == 'Expiring 10-days':
        dff_merged = df_10_days
        return dff_merged.to_dict('records')

    if value == 'Expiring 15-days':
        dff_merged = df_15_days
        return dff_merged.to_dict('records')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug='True', host='0.0.0.0', port=7777)
```

Comment: https://pixeldrain.com/u/PQdJGYkQ
Copied my Input CSV file here.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, but if you want to filter the `df` dataframe by date ranges, for example those that are expiring within 5 days; then you can do `df_expiring_list_in_5_days = df[(expiry_date_5_days > pd.to_datetime(df.endDate))]`

Comment: Hi @DanielAlMouiee - Thank you much for response. What you suggested is really is what I need. But with using REM column. Translated your line with `df_5_days = df[(0 > pd.to_datetime(df.REM))]`. This gave me error "TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and int". Changed it to `df_5_days = df[(0 > pd.to_datetime(int(df.REM)))]` but this gives error "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>"

Comment: More Explanation of Problem: The Table to update from dropdown is based on REM column in table. The cases are if REM `less than or equal to ZERO`. Case 2 is REM `equal to 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5`. Case 3 is REM `equal to 6 till 10` and so on. On each case if the Row has REM falling in between those case ranges, the callback to return those rows.

Comment: 16 hours of research and testing, finally resolved it. Solution is similar to what @DanielAlMouiee suggested but replace df.endDate with df.REM and use brackets for range. Without brackets doesn't work.

Comment: great glad to hear you got it to work after you trying and testing it out, best way to improve and build expertise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution usage as follows:

```
df_0_days = df[df.REM <= 0]
df_5_days = df[(df.REM >= 1) & (df.REM <= 5)]
df_10_days = df[(df.REM >= 6) & (df.REM <= 10)]
df_15_days = df[(df.REM >= 11) & (df.REM <= 15)]
```

Comment: Great, perhaps mark it as the solution to your problem so it's clear to other people that this has been solved